# Autofs BROWSE Mode in CentOS\RHEL

Tags: centos5, rhel5, autofs

I have multiple server mounting their $HOME from a file server. 
On the clients I have set in /etc/sysconfig/autofs

```
 BROWSE_MODE="no"
```

The client also mount directories from other files servers to /shared and /cifs
I was wondering if there is a way to control BROWSE_MODE specifically for different
maps, e.g I want to have BROWSE_MODE=yes for /shared and /cifs.

I saw in the Arch Wiki and Gentoo the flag --ghost, can I use it in RHEL/CENTOS ?

I am thinking about changing to

```
BROWSE_MODE="yes"
```

And then in auto.master

```
shared  auto.shared -rw,grpid,hard,intr,nodevs,nosuid (some ghost option here?)
```

It [seems that --ghost mode is available](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/5.7_Technical_Notes/index.html) in centos 5.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

I got it myself. The documentation about it is quite lacking in Red Hat, but we do have Arch Wiki :-)

So, Adding the flag --ghost to specific maps will show them.

Now my setting look like this:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/autofs
#
#
BROWSE_MODE="no"
#EOF 

# cat /etc/auto.master
/home /etc/auto.home  
/shared   auto.share -rw,grpid,hard,intr,nodevs,nosuid --ghost
```

So `ls /home`  does not show anything, and `ls /shared` does show the stuff. 
The meaning of `--ghost` is that ghost directories are created even though the automounter
does not mount them.